# Cypher count instances greater than

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am writing a query to display a graph comprising of all the journals and their publication place (cities). I would like to filter the query by selecting only the Cities which are the publication place of more than 3 journals.
My attempt does give me cities and the count but I cannot manage to have the journal.name and the relationship in the result

```
MATCH (j:journal)-[p:publication_city]->(c:City)
WITH c, count(c) as cnt
WHERE cnt > 3
RETURN c, cnt
ORDER BY cnt
```

Whatever change to add the journal variable in the query above (e.g. `WITH c, count(c) as cnt, j`) lead to empty result
Anyone who knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use COLLECT clause to get all journals with more than 3 publications. Then UNWIND to list them out one by one.  UNWIND is like a "for loop" in sql.

```
MATCH (j:journal)-[:publication_city]-(c:city) 
WITH c, count(c) as cnt, collect(j) as journals WHERE cnt > 3
UNWIND journals as journal
RETURN journal, c, cnt
ORDER BY cnt
```

Comment: Thank you, it appears to work splendidly.However, would it be possible to return also the relationship ?

Comment: please edit your SO question then will reply

Comment: added to the original question